# Upload images according to position no firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I'm creating a system for storing multiple image links in firestore, and it's been working, I select from the gallery and upload them as List  it is in the order that it is going to the bank (firestore ), because it matters to me, I select for example the images 1,2,3, and when I save their link in the firestore it gets 2,1,3 or 3,1, 2 or 3,2,1 never in the order I loaded, it seems to be according to the lightest image, as saved according to the position I loaded? I've been breaking my head with this for a few days.

already  to get each image from List.get(i) to save but to no avail.

I'm saving like this in firestore ->
list_img [
0 link_img
1 link_img
2 link_img]

[firestore scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nryBS.png)

upload from gallery

```
GalleryConfig config = new GalleryConfig.Build()
                .limitPickPhoto(50)
                .singlePhoto(false)
                .hintOfPick("this is pick hint")
                .filterMimeTypes(new String[]{})
                .build();
        GalleryActivity.openActivity(Pag_producao_hq.this, reqCode, config);
```

upload

```
private void upload_Fotos_selecionadas(Uri uri, final int totalimg, int i) {
        Log.i("sdsd77", String.valueOf(i));
        final StorageReference ImageFolder =  FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("imagens");
        String nomeImagem = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        final StorageReference imagename = ImageFolder
                .child("HQ")
                .child(identificadorUsuario)
                .child(nomeImagem);
      arrayListImageRef.add(ImageFolder); //arraylist of type StorageRef 

        arrayListImageRef.add(imagename);
        imagename.putFile(uri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        imagename.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                               String urlConvertida = uri.toString();

                                lista_url.add(urlConvertida);


                                if(lista_url.size()==totalimg){
                            Map<String, Object> new_imagens = new HashMap<>();
                              new_imagens.put("list_img", lista_url);

                              db.collection("HQ")
                                  .document(getId())
                             .collection("Imagens")
                              .add(new_imagens);

                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        if (!isFinishing()) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Firestore does not list document as the same order of insertion. Auto IDs are not time related. You will need to add a timestamp field and query your data using order by this field.

Comment: I'm saving like this in firestore ->
list_img [
0 link_img
1 link_img
2 link_img] because otherwise I can not save all images, what would be the best way?

Comment: Firestore -> auto generated ID1 {timestamp and image link1},auto generated ID2 {timestamp and image link2}